# Перерисовка полей ввода параметров

Tags: c++, qt

Есть счётная программа, в которой используется несколько методов, выбор метода реализован с помощью `comboBox`:
[image: Выбор метода счёта]

Все параметры делятся на основные (общие для каждого метода) и специфические (под каждый метод свои параметры):
[image: Окно параметров (основные)]

И т.к. методов счёта становится всё больше и больше, то и окно параметров превращается в длинное полотно, которое надо листать.

Что хочется: реализовать перерисовку полей ввода в зависимости от выбранного метода счёта; т.е. поля ввода основных параметров отрисованы всегда, а ниже показаны только параметры выбранного алгоритма, остальные поля не отображаются.

[image: Поля ввода специфических параметров]

Не знаю, как такое реализовать. Это поди нужна какая-то группировка полей ввода?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, посмотрите в сторону QStackedWidget

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, да, направление верное, только QStackedWidget показывает один виджет из набора, а мне надо группу виджетов (поля ввода и подписи к ним)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver и непонятно, как это всё подружить с QScrollArea

Comment: На каждой вкладке stacked widget располагаете свой набор полей ввода, специфичный для данного метода. Если для нескольких методов поля совпадают, увы, придется дублировать. `QScrollArea` видимо надо засовывать в каждую вкладку. А вообще я бы пересмотрел интерфейс, возможно, в сторону `QTableWidget`